# BeforeBuild target never gets executed in some projects

Tags: c#, csproj

This is .csproj instructions I'd like to be executed:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <DisableFastUpToDateCheck>true</DisableFastUpToDateCheck>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Exec Command="powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -command &quot;&amp; 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Build Test\testScript.ps1' &quot;" />
  </Target>
```

I've tested it in multiple project. In all but one of them it works -> it starts the powershell script as expected.

This is the slightly truncated .csproj for the project where it fails:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <Authors>me</Authors>
    <Company>Company</Company>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <PackageRequireLicenseAcceptance>true</PackageRequireLicenseAcceptance>
    <Copyright></Copyright>
    <PackageLicenseUrl></PackageLicenseUrl>
    <PackageProjectUrl></PackageProjectUrl>
    <PackageIconUrl />
    <RepositoryUrl></RepositoryUrl>
    <PackageTags></PackageTags>
    <PackageReleaseNotes>Release message</PackageReleaseNotes>
    <Title>MyProjectLib</Title>
    <Summary>sTUFF</Summary>
    <Description>My Project library</Description>
    <Version>4.2.5</Version>
    <AssemblyVersion>1.0.0</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion>1.0.0</FileVersion>
    <RootNamespace>MyProjectLib</RootNamespace>
    <PackageId>MyProjectLib</PackageId>
    <Product>MyProjectLib</Product>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>    
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup Label="dotnet pack instructions">
    <Content Include="build\*.targets">
      <Pack>true</Pack>
      <PackagePath>build\</PackagePath>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="CollectRuntimeOutputs" BeforeTargets="_GetPackageFiles">
    <!-- Collect these items inside a target that runs after build but before packaging. -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <Content Include="$(OutputPath)\*.pdb;">
        <Pack>true</Pack>
        <PackagePath>build\</PackagePath>
      </Content>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>


  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
    <DocumentationFile>bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\MyProject.xml</DocumentationFile>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;VERBOSE_WARNINGS</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
    <DocumentationFile>bin\Release\netstandard2.0\MyProject.xml</DocumentationFile>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;FINAL</DefineConstants>
    <DebugType>none</DebugType>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Contrib\**" />
    <Compile Remove="Folder2\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="Contrib\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="Folder2\**" />
    <None Remove="Contrib\**" />
    <None Remove="Folder2\**" />
  </ItemGroup>
  
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http" Version="2.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" Version="4.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Win32.Registry" Version="4.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Portable.BouncyCastle" Version="1.8.5.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Management" Version="5.0.0-preview.1.20120.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Memory" Version="4.5.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="ExternalProject.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="mscorlib" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <!--START OF IMPORTANT STUFF-->
  <PropertyGroup>
    <DisableFastUpToDateCheck>true</DisableFastUpToDateCheck>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Exec Command="powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -command &quot;&amp; 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Build Test\testScript.ps1' &quot;" />
  </Target>

  <!--END OF IMPORTANT STUFF-->
  
</Project>
```

I've spent the last day figuring out why it fails to execute powershell script.. What could be the reason for the failure?

Comment: Check if this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44829863/2109769

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `Sdk` import, it will add content before and after your project file and overwriting the `BeforeBuild` target (this is why in non-sdk projects this target should be at the very bottom below any `<Import>`s.

I suggest creating a target without a conflicting name and hooking it into the build:

```
<Target Name="RunCustomScript" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
```

This is also what the Project Property Pages dialog in VS should generate when you try to edit build scripts.